# creating a board from a list

Tags: python, list

Say, I have a list ['0-0-0','10-1-2','15-2-3','6-4-5']. I would like to define a function to create a board so that it shows like this:

```
Diamond Sword Enemie
0       0     0
10      1     2
15      2     3
6       4     5
```

so here's my code:

```
def create_lists_board(listStrings):
    lists_board=[]
    biome_biome=["Biome#",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    biome_diam=["Diam"]
    biome_sword=["Sword"]
    biome_enemy=["Enemy"]
    for i in listStrings:
        n=i.split("-")
        biome_diam.append(int(n[0]))
        biome_sword.append(int(n[1]))
        biome_enemy.append(int(n[2]))

    lists_board=biome_biome+biome_diam+biome_sword+biome_enemy
    return lists_board
```

It's wrong and I don't know why

Comment: What is wrong? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_lists_board(listStrings):

    print "Diamond Sword Enemy"
    for i in listStrings:
        n = i.split("-")
        print "%s \t %s \t %s"%(str(n[0]), str(n[1]), str(n[2]))

create_lists_board(['0-0-0','10-1-2','15-2-3','6-4-5'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use string formatting here:

```
lis = "Diamond Sword Enemie".split()
lis1 = ['0-0-0','10-1-2','15-2-3','6-4-5']
print "{:10} {:^8} {:>10}".format(*lis)
for x in lis1:
     print "{:10} {:^8} {:>10}".format(*x.split('-'))
```

**Output:**

```
Diamond     Sword       Enemie
0             0              0
10            1              2
15            2              3
6             4              5
```